# How do i get rid of burnt smell from kheer?

Tags: burnt

when we cook **kheer** it happens most of the time **kheer** burnt and stick with saucepan.The smell of burnt **kheer** transfer into whole **kheer** and it tasted not good.What can i do in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [recipe at Wikibooks cookbook](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cookbook:Kheer) acknowledges this is an issue:

> The main difficulty in this dish is preventing the kheer from sticking to the bottom of the pan, that requires care.

So cook very gently indeed and stir a lot. You may even want to turn the heat off for a few minutes at a time, then turn back on low and stir constantly for a few minutes, as much of the milk is absorbed into the rice. However some of the thickening comes from cooking the milk, so as it starts to thicken you need to stir constantly.

Other recipes use more milk and reduce it further. It's almost impossible to stop that sticking on the bottom, but a heavy-based pan and gentle heat should mean that the stuck solids don't actually burn. Once it starts to stick I would stir without scraping the bottom of the pan.

You may be able to find a cheat's recipe that uses evaporated milk in place of (some of) the milk. That would mean much less reducing, and therefore less time for it to stick.

Comment: I wouldn't accept this just yet, give other people time to respond, as they may have more or better ideas

Answer (score 3):

Use a nonstick saucepan. While there can still be some caramelization, at least burnt stuff will not stick and get burnt further.

Also, consider using the oven if you have one: Preheat the oven to 110-120°C, while bringing the pot and kheer up to temperature on the stove. Place the hot pot in the oven - this will keep it at slow cooking temperature but make it impossible to reach sufficient temperature to quickly burn anything....